# Lab 2012 Hyper-v migration from esxi

Tags: sql-server, virtualization, virtualhost, hyper-v

I need some clarity on the hyper-v virtualization strategy coming from ESXi 4.x.

Purpose:
A VM for Sql Server 2012 w/ SP1
A VM for Sql Server 2014 CPT1

Hardware:
Poweredge T100 8GB RAM, 2 SSDs JBOD and a 2TB 7200 WD backup drive. This is lab hardware for learning.

Problem:
I am confused as to what the "free" Hyper-V server is for.

My understanding is that it will be the Host OS and the Guest OS will be 2012 Standard. Is this correct?

Comment: I've edited the licensing portion out of the question, because we do not answer licensing questions here. For that, you should reach out to your license reseller. I have, however, answered your first question, which is the difference between Hyper-V Server and Server 2012 with the Hyper-V role.

Comment: @MDMarra thank you. That is much more relevant to what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To relate thing to your VMWare background - Hyper-V Server is similar to ESXi. It is a stripped down hypervisor and is very lightweight. It is meant to be managed remotely and advanced configuration like NIC teaming is typically done with PowerShell.

You can also run the Hyper-V role on a full install of Windows Server. This is the exact same hypervisor, but you have a full server GUI to run the management tools and do configuration with. This option requires the physical host to be licensed, Hyper-V server does not.

Comment: Ok now I got it. Many thanks now I know what to ask for. Any recommendations on Powerhsell management of the Hyper-V Server? Especially interested on e-books for the putting on my Kindle. This course looks promising: [link]http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=powershell-and-sql-server&highlight=robert-cain_powershell-and-sql-server-m1-dbatasks!robert-cain_powershell-and-sql-server-m6-sqlpsexample#powershell-and-sql-server-m1-dbatasks